# Correct way of computing norm $L_2$ for a finite difference scheme

Tags: finite-difference, error-estimation, accuracy

I am computing the rate of convergence of my finite difference scheme in norm $L_2$. Which is the correct way to compute it? This:

\begin{align}
  L_2     &= \frac{1}{N}\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^N(u^{numerical}_j-u^{exact}_j)^2}        \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; (1)\\ 
\end{align}

or this:

\begin{align}
  L_2     &= \sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=1}^N(u^{numerical}_j-u^{exact}_j)^2} \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; (2)\\
\end{align}

where $u^{numerical}$ is the computed along-x velocity at velocity point $j$, with $j=1..N$, and $u^{exact}$ is the analytical solution. In some publications I saw the second option, but that clashes against the fact that norm $L_2$ should be always smaller than norm $L_1$ (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245052/showing-that-l2-norm-is-smaller-than-l1 ). However here norms are "scaled" so I guess that inequality should hold only for the unscaled version. Note that if one uses (1) the inequality still holds. 
In Leveque's book a pag 140 the error is defined as:

\begin{align}
  L_2     &= \sqrt{\Delta{x} \sum_{j=1}^N(u^{numerical}_j-u^{exact}_j)^2} \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; (3)\\
\end{align}

Although this would be strictly true for a finite volume method, if we extend it to a finite difference method and to two dimension, by division by the total active area of the domain one gets equation (2). This question is related to question [Why a finite difference scheme would give second order of accuracy in norm L2 but 1.5 with L1 (while 1 with Linf)?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/19746/why-a-finite-difference-scheme-would-give-second-order-of-accuracy-in-norm-l2-bu) , since I see that the order of accuracy is larger than the thoretical value of 2 if I use equation (1), while it is smaller if I use equation (2). Which one is the best formulation?

Comment: Why the $1/N$ coefficient?

Comment: Well you need to scale the norm, if you remove 1/N  you cannot compute the rate of convergence, For example if one refines the grid by halving the grid spacing in x and y, one has four times the number of grid cells and if the error is 4 times smaller in each point => L2 stays constant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Use equation (2), equation (1) is wrong.

Technically the $L^2$ norm (upper case "L") is an integral norm of a function [defined as](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L2-Norm.html)
$$
\left|\left|f(x)\right|\right|_2 = \sqrt{ \int_\Omega |f(x)|^2 dx}.
$$
I'm sure you meant $l^2$.

What you typically want to compute in the context of convergence of numerical methods is the finite dimensional analog of the $L^2$ norm which is an area-normalized version of the $l^2$ norm, meaning
$$
\left|\left|f\right|\right| = \sqrt{\sum_i \left|f_i\right|^2 \Delta x_i}
$$
Note that $\Delta x$ is inside the square root.

In practice, the area of the domain is just a constant that you don't really care about and the step size ($\Delta x$) is often a constant so you can just use your equation (2). Equation (1) is off by a factor of $1/\sqrt{N}$ so you will underestimate your error for large $N$.

Comment: If you are comparing functions on different meshes, you want to use the form that includes $N$ or $\Delta x$.

Comment: @BillBarth Yes, I thought that was clear. Perhaps I should (or you can) edit the answer to make it more explicit?

Comment: Ok, as I thought thanks. Therefore, it s not true that norm L2 should be always smaller than norm L1 as pointed in the math.stackexchange link. That was only for the vectorial unscaled norm.